# replace column in file with portion of filename linux

Tags: linux, replace, find

I have a serious of thousands files named in the following manner:

Track_0000000_extract.txt

where the zeros can be replaced with any numerical value.

The contents of these files look as follows:

```
1 0 138.7936 26.4674 -1.517 7.225 0 1 95564.477 100997.425 267127.576 44.585 215803.887 
1 6 138.4649 27.8692 -2.318 4.902 0 1 96308.418 101000.391 240804.857 40.122 239866.492 
1 12 137.956 28.8204 -2.196 6.239 0 1 96602.983 100980.098 193555.58 43.644 227623.588 
1 18 137.4698 30.031 -2.734 6.457 0 1 96763.473 100962.086 189049.294 42.996 132256.485 
1 24 136.857 31.2838 -2.595 1.886 0 1 97331.108 100934.865 120323.785 39.545 177050.848 
1 30 136.2677 31.6498 -5.708 -2.484 0 1 97295.779 100920.752 144810.457 37.85 23238.046
```

I would like to replace the number 1 in the first column of every file with the numerical value from the file name.  Is it possible to do this in the linux shell easily for all my thousands of files at once?

Thanks,
Kimberly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create files with the `.new` extension which have the first column replaced by the numerical value.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in Track_*_extract.txt
do
    num=${file#Track_}
    num=${num%_extract.txt}
    awk -v num=$num '{ $1=num; print }' < $file > $file.new
done
```

If you want the number in the first column to be replaced by the numerical value only if it is the number 1 - it wasn't clear to me what you wanted - then use this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in Track_*_extract.txt
do
    num=${file#Track_}
    num=${num%_extract.txt}
    awk -v num=$num '{ if ($1 == 1) { $1=num }; print }' < $file > $file.new
done
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly for my situation.  Thanks!  I will keep this in mind for future problems that arise.  These seems to be a common issue for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner:

```
find -name 'Track*_extract.txt' | \
      cut -d_ -f2 | \
      xargs -n 1 -I @ sed -i 's!^[^ ]*!'@'!' Track_@_extract.txt
```